# Quandl ingestion with zipline lacks data

Tags: python, finance, quantitative-finance, quandl, zipline

I have recently installed Zipline and ingested Quandl data. However, it seems that Quandl hasn't ingested data of the years 2018,2019 and 2020. Just by plotting a stock price you can see this.

AAPL stock 2016-2020:

[image: AAPL stock 2016-2020]

Why would this happen? Quandl free data doesn't seem to have restrictions on recent data. I am newbie on this topis and on this tools and it is quite frustrating.

Comment: What's the code that generated this plot?

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon for Quandl to stop updating free datasets, either because the underlying data source disappears or for some other reason. Their focus as a company is elsewhere (primarily on alternative data sold to institutions).

If you want to work with Zipline, your best bet is either to use [Quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com) (which is free but does not support live trading) or [QuantRocket](https://www.quantrocket.com/zipline/) (which has a free tier and supports live trading).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Have you ever tried to ingest another data provider ? How it could be done?